# How can I hide the simplistic photo editing buttons in Shotwell?

Tags: customization, interface, shotwell

I never use these buttons:

[image: Crop, Red-eye, Adjust, Enhance]

How can I make them go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: You can't, those buttons are part of the UI.

**Long answer**: There's a couple of options.  Shotwell is open source/free software, so of course you're welcome to download the source and modify it to suit your needs.  You could also file a Shotwell ticket for a preference to disable that toolbar.  It's probably not a feature we're likely to add unless there's more demand for it.

You can file a ticket here:
http://trac.yorba.org/newticket